# Expressions and arithemetics in common lisp functions

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function such that P(x) for any integer x there is a list of three elements, namely the square, cube, and fourth power of n but I'm stuck on how i can combine then to make one function for example i have the square, cube and the power 4 function
here are my functions below

```
(defun p(x) (* x x))

(defun p(x) (* x x x))

(defun p(x) (expt x x) //thought i am not sure about this one
```

is there a way i can make my result(i.e  `function p(x)` ) list look like  `(4 27 256)` if I have a list of  `( 2 3 4)`  after executing the program? Was thinking of `mapcar function` though I'm not sure on how I can go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to create a list, how about the function `LIST`?

Comment: i thought about it but im just a newbie dont know how to manipulate the functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `mapcar` could be a way to go.

```
;; a simple solution.
(defun expt-list (n powers)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (expt n x)) powers))

;; a bit more complex, so you  don't compute powers of the same 
;; base multiple times.
(defun expt-list-memoize (n powers)
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table)))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                (let ((y (gethash x hash)))
                  (if y y (setf (gethash x hash) (expt n x)))))
            powers)))
```

Comment: how do i enter the numbers or arguments its giving some error i do not know why

Comment: im getting expt-list at the end but when i enter (expt-list 2 3 5) its not working,am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There is one oddity in Common Lisp, that one has to recognize: If you want to refer to a function via a symbol, you will have to quote it with (function p) or with the abbrevation #'p

Given

`(defun p(x) (* x x))`

you can compute a list of squares with

`CL-USER> (mapcar #'p (list 1 2 3 4))`

`(1 4 9 16)`

Answer (score 0):

The requirements here are a little fuzzy but if the intent is, given a call such as `(expt-list 2 3 4)` to have returned a list of each number raised to its own power, eg:

```
(expt-list 2 3 4)
=> (4 27 256)
```

would something along the lines of:

```
(defun expt-list (&rest list-of-n)
  "return a list of each 'n' in LIST-OF-N raised to its own power"
  (loop for n in list-of-n collect (expt n n)))
```

do the trick?